# Is there unexpected number result for Counter.most_common

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, counter

```
from collections import Counter

# Frequency table for a list of numbers
def frequency_table(numbers):
    table=Counter(numbers)
    for number in table.most_common():
        print('{0} \t {1}'.format(number[0],number[1]))
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    scores=[7,8,9,2,10,9,9,9,9,4,5,6,1,5,6,7,8,6,1,10]
    frequency_table(scores)
```

After I run this, the 2 term turns into twenty  one, I try many times, I put the results below

9 5
6 3
7 2
8 2
10 2
5 2
1 2
twenty one
4 1

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the code you provided. It seems to work as expected.

Comment: Hi, i try many times, as long as there is 2 in the list , the weird results twenty one shows. I never met something like that before

Comment: It works fine. But you can add `: in  print('{0} :\t{1}'.format(number[0],number[1]))`, this will make understanding easier.

Answer (score 1):

you have a list of integers and you create counter from it so:

```
[7,8,9,2,10,9,9,9,9,4,5,6,1,5,6,7,8,6,1,10]
```

becomes

```
Counter({7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 5, 2: 1, 10: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 1: 2})
```

which most_common items is a list of tuples which elements are integers:

So, I do not see anything odd in the output.

```
[(9, 5), (6, 3), (7, 2), (8, 2), (10, 2), (5, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (4, 1)]
```

the most common list has 9 elements which equals to number of key, value pair of the Counter.

in the most common list tuple `(2,1)` exists

you can print it as:

```
for x,y in Counter(scores).most_common():
    print(f"{x} {y}")
```

print output:

```
9 5
6 3
7 2
8 2
10 2
5 2
1 2
2 1
4 1
```